# Правильная настройка чпу ссылки

Tags: php

RewriteRule ^успешная-оплата/([a-zA-Z]+)/ SucessPayPage.php?token=$1 Какой параметр нужно написать что бы / здесь / были доступны и символы и цифры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цифры, символы и знак "_"

```
^успешная-оплата/(\w+)/
```

или ваш же вариант, только:

```
^успешная-оплата/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/
```